# Can't display decimals numbers

Tags: php, wordpress, decimal

I'm trying to make a WordPress plugin show decimal numbers in frontend. It does use them during calculation but it doesn't show them. What could I do? *sorry for bad english

This is the function.

```
if( isset($request['discount']) && is_array($request['discount']) ){

        $discount = $request['discount'];
        $code = $discount['code'];
        $data = check_available_coupon($code);
        if( $data ){
            $time_used = get_post_meta($data->ID,'time_used_discount', true);
            $time_limit = get_post_meta($data->ID,'time_limit', true);

            if ( $time_limit && $time_used > $time_limit){
                return 0;
            }
            $value = get_post_meta($data->ID,'value', true);
            $type = get_post_meta($data->ID,'type', true);


            if( empty($type) || $type == 'percent' ){
                $discount_amount = $value*$subtotal/100;
            } else {
                $discount_amount = $value;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? We can't help fix it if we don't know what it is!

Comment: someone edited my post. basically the plugin doesn't show decimal number in frontend but it uses them during calculations.

Comment: _“This is the function”_ - a), that is not a function, and b) we have no idea where the values this calculates (and that is all the code you have shown does) are eventually getting output to the page.

Comment: The edit only fixed the code formatting, it didn't remove any relevant information. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to give us the information we need to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) that contains all the functions for formatting a decimal point number.

Comment: I tried looking at that. But i don't know really how to implement it. I tried like this but it doesn't work.

Comment: if( empty($type) || $type == 'percent' ){
     $discount_amount = $value*$subtotal/100;
     echo number_format((float)$discount_amount, 2, '.', '');
    } else {
     $discount_amount = $value;
     echo number_format((float)$discount_amount, 2, '.', '');
    }

   }
  }
  return max($discount_amount, 0);
  echo number_format((float)$discount_amount, 2, '.', '');